# Custom REST routes in CakePHP

Tags: php, rest, http, cakephp, routes

I want to define a custom REST route using CakePHP. I am able to create route as `post/user/:id`. Here is the related code in my `routes.php`:

```
Router::connect(
    "/pool/user/:id",
    array(
        '[method]' => 'DELETE',
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action' => 'delete',         
    )
);
```

Now I want to create a route a route as `post/:id/user/:id`, where the first `id` is the post id and the second `id` is user id. But when I do so it gives me an error:

```
 preg_match(): Compilation failed: two named subpatterns have the same name at offset 39 [CORE/Cake/Routing/Route/CakeRoute.php, line 195]
```

How do I create the desired REST route?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear about what is wrong, you can't have two or more named elements with the same name.

The solution should be rather obvious, use unique names for your elements

```
post/:postId/user/:userId
```